# How can I change "_Ctype_int" to "int" in GO?

Tags: c, go, types, slice, swig

I have a slice that I need to change from _Ctype_int to int.

```
fmt.Printf("Slice Type: %T", slice) //Returns Slice Type: []main._Ctype_int
```

Do you know of a simple conversion? Thank you!

Here is the code that returns a pointer to array in C++

```
   #include "camera.hxx"
   #include <iostream>

   Camera::Camera()
   {
   }

   int* Camera::retrieveDataPointerPerBuffer() {
     const int size = 640 * 512;
     static int cameraData[size]; 
     for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
     cameraData[i] = i;
      } //Generates dummy 512x640 camera data
      int* pSrc = cameraData;
      return pSrc;
   } //C++ file
```

This code calls the c++ function in Go.

```
func myCamera() {
    cam := camera.NewCamera()
    pSrc := cam.RetrieveDataPointerPerBuffer()

    arraySize := 512 * 640
    slice := (*[1 << 30]C.int)(unsafe.Pointer(pSrc))[:arraySize:arraySize]

    fmt.Printf("\nSlice Type: %T\n", slice)
 }

 func main() {
     go myCamera()
     time.Sleep(15 * time.Millisecond)
 }
```

I am using SWIG to wrap the C++ for Go

Comment: Can you please provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) ?

Comment: @Rafael Auyer Just edited the answer

Comment: Is [thread](https://forum.golangbridge.org/t/nice-way-to-convert-int-to-c-int/5351/3)  this helpful to you ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The size of a C `int` and a Go `int` are implementation dependent and they are not necessarily the same.

---

For example, to convert between different memory layouts,

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "unsafe"
)

import "C"

func main() {
    cInts := []C.int{0, 1, 2}
    fmt.Println(C.sizeof_int, cInts)
    goInts := make([]int, len(cInts))
    for i, ci := range cInts {
        goInts[i] = int(ci)
    }
    fmt.Println(unsafe.Sizeof(int(0)), goInts)
}
```

Output:

```
4 [0 1 2]
8 [0 1 2]
```

---

```
$ go version
go version devel +0349f29a55 Thu Feb 21 15:14:45 2019 +0000 linux/amd64
$ gcc --version
gcc (Ubuntu 8.2.0-7ubuntu1) 8.2.0
$ g++ --version
g++ (Ubuntu 8.2.0-7ubuntu1) 8.2.0
$
```